# Finding Median Using MySQL

Tags: sql, median

I know that there are many ways to find the median, but I am trying to use this method to find the median. Can someone explain to me why this does not work? The error here says "Invalid use of group function," but when I use HAVING instead of WHERE, the system doesn't recognize what RowNumber is. I'm very confused.

```
SELECT
    ROUND(AVG(LS.LAT_N))
FROM(
    SELECT
        LAT_N,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LAT_N) AS RowNumber
    FROM
        STATION
    ) AS LS
WHERE
    RowNumber IN (
        IF(
            FLOOR(COUNT(LS.LAT_N)/2+0.5) = CEIL(COUNT(LS.LAT_N)/2+0.5),
            FLOOR(COUNT(LS.LAT_N)/2+0.5),
            FLOOR(COUNT(LS.LAT_N)/2+0.5) AND CEIL(COUNT(LS.LAT_N)/2+0.5)
            )
```

Comment: `but I am trying to use this method` ... please explain what "this" method is.  Without knowing the method, we probably can't give a complete answer.

Comment: There is a much simpler solution involving two row numbers (asc and desc) and filtering rows where the two numbers match.

Answer (score 1):

The median is the middle element in an ordered series - or the average of the two middle elements if there is an even number.

```
SELECT
    AVG(LAT_N)
FROM(
    SELECT
        LAT_N,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LAT_N) AS RowNumber
    FROM
        STATION
    ) AS q
WHERE
RowNumber >= FLOOR ( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STATION)/2 + 0.5)
AND
RowNumber <= CEIL ( (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM STATION)/2 + 0.5)
```

Here is dbfiddle https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b31e08f4ece61ecb95d9dde76c389fb1

Comment: What COUNT(*) is an even number? In that case, wouldn't I need to find the average of the middle 2 numbers instead of just returning one number?

Comment: Oops -  changed it to take that into account.

Comment: This doesn't work:  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6babfb9f743ba5ccb059296cc2601f34.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Oops - fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I typically write this as:

```
SELECT AVG(LAT_N)
FROM (SELECT LAT_N,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY LAT_N) AS RowNumber,
             COUNT(*) OVER () as cnt
      FROM STATION
     ) s
WHERE 2 * RowNumber IN (CNT, CNT + 1, CNT + 2);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b8295931185b993146b2e3f9e2ded146) is a db<>fiddle.