# Median calculation for the given data using MySQL

Tags: mysql

A median is defined as a number separating the higher half of a data set from the lower half. Query the median of the Northern Latitudes (LAT_N) from STATION and round your answer to  decimal places.

```
SELECT ROUND(LAT_N, 4),
CASE
    WHEN (SELECT COUNT(LAT_N) FROM STATION) % 2 != 0 THEN
        (SELECT LAT_N FROM STATION ORDER BY LAT_N ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET (SELECT (COUNT(LAT_N) + 1) / 2       FROM STATION))
    ELSE
        (SELECT LAT_N FROM STATION ORDER BY LAT_N ASC LIMIT 1 OFFSET (SELECT (COUNT(LAT_N) / 2) + ((COUNT(LAT_N) + 2) / 2) FROM STATION))
END AS median_lat
FROM STATION;
```

I am expecting the median but getting error every time

Comment: *"getting error every time"* What's the error?

Comment: For the even number of rows case, you should take the average of the two middlemost rows.

Comment: MySQL does not allow you to use a subquery for the [LIMIT/OFFSET arguments](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html#:~:text=LIMIT%20takes%20one%20or%20two%20numeric%20arguments%2C%20which%20must%20both%20be%20nonnegative%20integer%20constants).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding Median Using MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68031255/finding-median-using-mysql)